# Clip raster image with bezier curve shape in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, mask

I have a raster image that I'm trying to 'cut out' a part of (then follow it with feathering + blending etc), I draw an "outline" with the bezier curve tool, afterwards making sure to close the newly drawn path. [image: example 1]

However, after doing this I want to 'set clip', leaving the selected area of the raster image behind. Unfortunately all this does is take the stroke of the bezier curve and clips that from the image, and not the enclosed shape.[image: example 2]

What is the correct order of operations in order to get the "cut out" shape from my raster?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: You are selecting just the path and the image, then doing set clip, correct? I can't replicate this problem with Inkscape 0.92. In fact, even if the path isn't closed, it still works for me. Are you on an older version?

Comment: I am using Inkscape v.92.

Answer (score 1):

There are Clips and Masks.

- A *clip* uses the *shape* of the upper object (regardless of color and so on) to cut out parts of the lower object.
- A *mask* uses the *color* of the upper object (can vary when using gradients, or a group of objects) to cut out parts of the lower object. White means 100% opacity and black means 0% opacity. Colors in between lead to partial visibility of the masked object.

You probably used *mask* (`Object > Mask > Set`) but wanted to use *clip* (`Object > Clip > Set`).

**edit:** "user unknown" provided the same answer and was faster.

Comment: with utmost certainty I used clip.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your behaviour in my (german) Inkscape, by generating such a path (bezier tool, rect, circle - no matter), marking the path and the image and selecting the 1st option of the **2nd** option of the third group of the object menue, which is in German Objekt/Maskierung/Setzen (Object/Masking/set), but the desired behaviour by the 1st of the **1st** option of the object menue, Objekt/Ausschneidepfad/setzen (object/cutting path/set).

Comment: they both the the exact same thing for me, (see result in 2nd picture of original post) no matter which order I select the objects in or if i choose set mask or set clip (in your case, cutting path)

Comment: Same behaviour if you make (just for testing) a path with a circle or rectangle?

Comment: No, if I use any other shape tool it behaves as expected. The only thing that doesn't work at all is the #D box tool.

Comment: #D switches the grid on or off for me. I thought you used the bezier tool (Form: none)?

Comment: sorry, typo, I meant to say 3D box tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is a really old question, however I think I know what caused the problem.

When the path was created, a Shape must have been applied in the tool controls such as "Triangle in". This is a path effect, and it will mess up the clip.

Remove the path effect before applying the clip. Path effects can be removed using *Path > Remove Path Effect*.